# Laravel assets, routes and url() not working when browse https after deploy in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

I use AWS elastic beanstalk to deploy my laravel project. Everything works well but my assets, routes and can't get real user ip.

Assets: It reference http when call asset() although I browse https. The site block to read http asset from https

Routes: Always points to http although I browse https

URL: Always return http although I browse https

IP: Always return server IP. Never get real user IP. But it works on other server but not in AWS elastic beanstalk

What should I do? Any solution welcome and will be grateful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

##### Two common issues when you use AWS or any other cloud Load Balancer:

1. `HTTPS` (Laravel asset and route): You applied SSL/TLS and the URL is protected in the browser but Laravel doesn't load your asset and throw an error. The error look like it blocks the URLS because of you are trying to load http URL http request. Most of the people facing this issue when use `AWS or any other cloud Load Balancer`. When running your applications behind a load balancer that terminates TLS / SSL certificates, you may notice your application sometimes does not generate HTTPS links when using the url helper. Typically this is because your application is being forwarded traffic from your load balancer on port 80 and does not know it should generate secure links.
2. `IP`: Another issue is IP issue. You can't get the user/visitor IP and it returns always server IP. This issue also happen because of `proxies`.

`Solution`: When you are using `AWS or any cloud Load Balancer` then you may not know the exact IP address of your actual `Loads Balancer` so should allow all proxies like below example.

Use `*` to allow trust all proxies in your `TrustProxies` middleware. Here is your middleware `app/Http/Middlewares/TrustProxies.php`.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var string|array
     */
     protected $proxies = '*';

    /**
     * The headers that should be used to detect proxies.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO;
```

If you are using AWS Elastic Load Balancing, your $headers value should be `Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB.` For more information on the constants that may be used in the $headers property, check out Symfony's documentation on [trusting proxies](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html).

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array|string
     */
    protected $proxies = '*';

    /**
     * The headers that should be used to detect proxies.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;
```

I think it solves your HTTPS, IP and other proxy related issue. To read more details read [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies).

`Solution 2` : There are another way to allow https by forcing in your `AppServiceProvider` or Create a new middleware to implement this. In my code snippet I decide to use `AppServiceProvider` because easy to implement. Open `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` in any text editor and write `$this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);`. You may extra check that APP in production mode.

```
if(request()->getRequestUri() != '/health' && $this->app->environment('production')) {
            $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
        }
```

`request()->getRequestUri() != '/health'`  used for `health check` of AWS ALB security group because it doesn't support https.

3. You may use `URL::forceScheme('https')` to force asset url as https.

Last solution 2 and 3 only for assets, https, and url() but won't for real IP. So I recommend use First solution because it works for all cases. If you don't want to allow proxies then Solution 2 is the most effective.

If you face any other issue or need improvements comments below.

Good luck. Enjoy!